# How to get to an Facebook post made on some give date in the past?

Tags: facebook

I want to find one Facebook user post that he made a bit more than one year ago. I began to scroll down the line of his posts hoping to reach the desired one, but quite soon I discovered that it's a daunting task. The posts don't get loaded at the speed of the mouse wheel, so I had to stop and wait every 30 seconds or so to wait till the next portion of posts is loaded into the browser's screen. Since the user made more than one posts a day, this turned out to be quite a tedious process. It took at the beginning about 5 minutes to scroll back in time only one month of his posts, but later, to my horror, I realized that the loading time for each portion of posts becomes longer the further back in time you go. All in all, it took me about one hour and a half to get to the post that was made 10 months ago and then the posts simply stopped loading. So I never got down to the desired post.

So is there any way to get to some particular post or a collection of posts made by FB user on a given date in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

At the top of their profile page, you should have an option to set some "Filters".

On a PC (Google Chrome), I see it like this:
[image: Facebook Filters Button]

I was able to filter to Year/Month/Day. Interesting!